# image processing algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, filter

I am trying to implement an algorithm described in this paper:

> [Decomposition of biospeckle images in temporary spectral bands](http://www.opticsinfobase.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=OL-30-13-1641)

Here is an explanation of the algorithm:

> We recorded a sequence of `N` successive speckle images with a sampling
>   frequency `fs`. In this way it was possible to observe how a pixel
>   evolves through the `N` images. That evolution can be treated as a time
>   series and can be processed in the following way: Each signal
>   corresponding to the evolution of every pixel was used as input to a
>   bank of filters. The intensity values were previously divided by their
>   temporal mean value to minimize local differences in reflectivity or
>   illumination of the object. The maximum frequency that can be
>   adequately analyzed is determined by the sampling theorem and s half
>   of sampling frequency `fs`. The latter is set by the CCD camera, the
>   size of the image, and the frame grabber. The bank of filters is
>   outlined in Fig. 1.
>
> [image: bank of filters]
>
> In our case, ten 5° order Butterworth filters
>   were used, but this number can be varied according to the required
>   discrimination. The bank was implemented in a computer using MATLAB
>   software. We chose the Butter-worth filter because, in addition to its
>   simplicity, it is maximally flat. Other filters, an infinite impulse
>   response, or a finite impulse response could be used.
>
> By means of this
>   bank of filters, ten corresponding signals of each filter of each
>   temporary pixel evolution were obtained as output. Average energy Eb
>   in each signal was then calculated:
>
> [image: energy equation]
>
> where `pb(n)` is the intensity of the filtered pixel in the nth image
>   for filter `b` divided by its mean value and `N` is the total number of
>   images. In this way, `En` values of energy for each pixel were obtained,
>   each of hem belonging to one of the frequency bands in Fig. 1.
>
> With these values it is possible to build ten images of the active object,
>   each one of which shows how much energy of time-varying speckle there
>   is in a certain frequency band. False color assignment to the gray
>   levels in the results would help in discrimination.

and here is my MATLAB code base on that :

```
for i=1:520
    for j=1:368
        ts = [];
        for k=1:600
            ts = [ts D{k}(i,j)]; %%% kth image pixel i,j --- ts is time series
        end
        ts = double(ts);
          temp = mean(ts);        
           if (temp==0)
                for l=1:10
                    filtImag1{l}(i,j)=0;
                end
                continue;
           end

         ts = ts-temp;          
         ts = ts/temp;    
        N = 5; % filter order
        W = [0.0 0.10;0.10 0.20;0.20 0.30;0.30 0.40;0.40 0.50;0.50 0.60 ;0.60 0.70;0.70 0.80 ;0.80 0.90;0.90 1.0];      
        [B,A]=butter(N,0.10,'low');
        ts_f(1,:) = filter(B,A,ts);         
        N1 = 5;                        
        for ind = 2:9           
            Wn = W(ind,:);
            [B,A] = butter(N1,Wn);            
            ts_f(ind,:) = filter(B,A,ts);            
        end        
        [B,A]=butter(N,0.90,'high');
        ts_f(10,:) = filter(B,A,ts); 

        for ind=1:10
          %Following Paper Suggestion          
           filtImag1{ind}(i,j) =sum(ts_f(ind,:).^2);
        end                 
    end
end

for i=1:10
  figure,imshow(filtImag1{i});  
  colorbar
end

pre_max = max(filtImag1{1}(:));
for i=1:10
   new_max = max(filtImag1{i}(:));
    if (pre_max<new_max)
        pre_max=max(filtImag1{i}(:));
    end
end
new_max = pre_max;

pre_min = min(filtImag1{1}(:));
for i=1:10
   new_min = min(filtImag1{i}(:));
    if (pre_min>new_min)
        pre_min = min(filtImag1{i}(:));
    end
end

new_min = pre_min;

%normalize
 for i=1:10
 temp_imag = filtImag1{i}(:,:);
 x=isnan(temp_imag);
 temp_imag(x)=0;
 t_max = max(max(temp_imag));
 t_min = min(min(temp_imag));
 temp_imag = (double(temp_imag-t_min)).*((double(new_max)-double(new_min))/double(t_max-t_min))+(double(new_min));

 %median filter
 %temp_imag = medfilt2(temp_imag);
 imag_test2{i}(:,:) = temp_imag;
 end

for i=1:10
  figure,imshow(imag_test2{i});
  colorbar
 end

for i=1:10
    A=imag_test2{i}(:,:);
    B=A/max(max(A));
    B=histeq(A);
 figure,imshow(B); 
 colorbar
 imag_test2{i}(:,:)=B;
end
```

but I am not getting the same result as paper. has anybody has any idea why? or where I have gone wrong?

**EDIT** 
by getting help from @Amro and using his code I endup with the following images:
here is my Original Image from 72hrs germinated Lentil (400 images, with 5 frame per second):  [image]

here is the results images for 10 different band :

[image: Band1] [image: Band2] [image: Band3] [image: Band4] [image: Band5] [image: Band6] [image: Band7] [image: BAnd8] [image: Band9] [image: Band10]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A couple of issue I can spot:

- when you divide the signal by its mean, you need to check that it was not zero. Otherwise the result will be `NaN`.
- the authors (I am following [this article](http://wheat.pw.usda.gov/ggpages/BarleyNewsletter/50/ARGBNL50.htm)) used a bank of filters with frequency bands covering the entire range up to the Nyquist frequency. You are doing half of that. The normalized frequencies you pass to `butter` should go all the way up to `1` (corresponds to `fs/2`)
- When computing the energy of each filtered signal, I think you should not divide by its mean (you have already accounted for that before). Instead simply do: `E = sum(sig.^2);` for each of the filtered signals
- In the last post-processing step, you should normalize to the range [0,1], and then apply the median filtering algorithm `medfilt2`. The computation doesn't look right, it should be something like:

  ```
  img = ( img - min(img(:)) ) ./ ( max(img(:)) - min(img(:)) );
  ```

---

#### EDIT:

With the above points in mind, I tried to rewrite the code in a vectorized way. Since you didn't post sample input images, I can't test if the result is as expected... Plus I am not sure how to interpret the final images anyway :)

```
%# read biospeckle images
fnames = dir( fullfile('folder','myimages*.jpg') );
fnames = {fnames.name};
N = numel(fnames);                    %# number of images
Fs = 1;                               %# sampling frequency in Hz
sz = [209 278];                       %# image sizes
T = zeros([sz N],'uint8');            %# store all images
for i=1:N
    T(:,:,i) = imread( fullfile('folder',fnames{i}) );
end

%# timeseries corresponding to every pixel
T = reshape(T, [prod(sz) N])';        %# columns are the signals
T = double(T);                        %# work with double class

%# normalize signals before filtering (avoid division by zero)
mn = mean(T,1);
T = bsxfun(@rdivide, T, mn+(mn==0));  %# divide by temporal mean

%# bank of filters
numBanks = 10;
order = 5;                                       % butterworth filter order
fCutoff = linspace(0, Fs/2, numBanks+1)';        % lower/upper cutoff freqs
W = [fCutoff(1:end-1) fCutoff(2:end)] ./ (Fs/2); % normalized frequency bands
W(1,1) = W(1,1) + 1e-5;                          % adjust first freq
W(end,end) = W(end,end) - 1e-5;                  % adjust last freq

%# filter signals using the bank of filters
Tf = cell(numBanks,1);                %# filtered signals using each filter
for i=1:numBanks
    [b,a] = butter(order, W(i,:));    %# bandpass filter
    Tf{i} = filter(b,a,T);            %# apply filter to all signals
end
clear T                               %# cleanup unnecessary stuff

%# compute average energy in each signal across frequency bands
Tf = cellfun(@(x)sum(x.^2,1), Tf, 'Uniform',false);

%# normalize each to [0,1], and build corresponding images
Tf = cellfun(@(x)reshape((x-min(x))./range(x),sz), Tf, 'Uniform',false);

%# show images
for i=1:numBanks
    subplot(4,3,i), imshow(Tf{i})
    title( sprintf('%g - %g Hz',W(i,:).*Fs/2) )
end
colormap(gray)
```

[image: screenshot]

*(I used the image from [here](http://lissi.fr/eric-delechelle/research/speckle/start) for the above result)*

#### EDIT#2

Made some changes and simplified the above code a bit. This shall reduce memory footprint. For example I used cell array instead of a single multidimensional matrix to store the result. That way we don't allocate one big block of contiguous memory. I also reused same variables instead of introducing new ones at each intermediate step...

Comment: thank you for your respond. im going to try your suggestions and will let you know the result soon

Comment: @user261002: I added my own implementation, take a look

Comment: you are are STAR. THANK YOU, but when I try to use your code it is only reply for the 30 images, and for more images it is giving me this error : ??? Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
Error in ==> SOmain at 39
E = squeeze( sum(Tf.^2,1) );
but I have to analysis my data for 400 images. also I am only getting images for the first 4 bands and the rest are completely while , so I assume we need to change the normalization a bit

Comment: @user261002: I made some changes to avoid out-of-memory errors on large number of images. If this is too big, you could unroll some of the vectorized code into explicit loops. Maybe even use `single` type instead of `double`...

Comment: @user261002: As for the final images, I say it again; Without examples of inputs/outputs, I am not sure what the expected result ought to be. So I leave those final tweaks to you...

Answer (score 7):

The paper doesn't mention subtracting the mean of the time series, are you sure that's necessary? Also, you only compute the new_max and new_min  once, from the last image.

Comment: hi @Junuxx I have followed the this link too: http://wheat.pw.usda.gov/ggpages/BarleyNewsletter/50/ARGBNL50.htm which has done exactly the same. do I need to compute the max and min for all the images??

Comment: @user261002: I'm not sure what the code is supposed to do, but it looks like you want the minimum/maximum across all images instead of the extremes of the last image. So you could do something like `if max(A(:)) > totalmax; totalmax = max(A(:)); end;` in the first loop. As a side node, `max(A(:))` looks nicer and should be faster than `max(max(A))`.